# Solve transport equations by using Laplace transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to solve rather formally one-dimensional transport equation:
$$
u_{t}+cu_{x}=0\quad\text{in $(0,\infty)\times(-\infty,\infty)$}
$$
with an initial data $u_{0}$, which is bounded and uniformly continuous, by using Laplace transform.

I now get
$$
\mathcal{L}[u(t,x)](s)=\frac{1}{c}\int_{-\infty}^{x}\exp\left(-\frac{s}{c}(x-y)\right)u_{0}(y)dy
$$
but I don't know how to get the function $u$.
The solution (in some weak sense if necessary) should have the form of $u(t,x)=u_{0}(x-ct)$ and so I'm going toward this form.

Please give hints, comments or solutions.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a substitution? $y=x-ct \implies dy=-cdt$, and
$$ \mathcal{L}[u(t,x)](s) = \frac{1}{c} \int_{-\infty}^x \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{s}{c}(x-y)\right)u_0(y)dy = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{exp}(-st)\,u_0(x-ct)\,dt,$$ So $u(t,x) = u_0(x-ct)$.